# Is there documentation for non-dynamically adding a 'many' to a 'one' in a 'one-to-many' relationship?

Tags: symfony

I have a `Customer` who has several `PhoneNumber`s.

The user creates a new `Customer` via a form, and I want him to be able to specify a single `PhoneNumber`.

Symfony's documentation tells me how to do this if the user were creating a `PhoneNumber` and had to also specify a `Customer` ([link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms)). It also tells me how to solve my problem using some Javascript, as described by the Cookbook's recipe for dynamically adding entities ([link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)).

What I'm missing is the part of the documentation where it simply describes a non-dynamic form that lets you add a single entity upon submission. So, the user fills out the customer's details, puts a phone number, and everything works out.

I suppose I could make a separate form, give it a `PhoneNumberType`, and then upon submission, call `$customer->addPhoneNumber($phoneNumber)`. But it seems like there should be a way to handle it through the relationships alone & in a single form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this question, I realize the answer is simple. In my controller,

```
// CustomerController.php
$customer = new Customer();

$phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
$customer->addPhoneNumber($phoneNumber);
```

Now when I build my form, I'll have a single blank `PhoneNumber` associated with the new `Customer`, and everything will persist as expected.